# Draw line that follows quadratic function in D3

Tags: d3.js

Assuming I have the quadratic function **(y = -0.1x^2 + 80)**, how could I draw a plot of this function in d3. Edit: to be more specific, I would like to graph this plot between a certain domain of two x coordinates (start and end).

Unfortunately I don't have much of an example to share currently. I've looked at using d3.arc but that doesn't appear to be the correct solution, and I'm currently considering generating data of many points that fall on the path of the function, and trying to connect those points with a path. If someone has had to do something like this before, and has good insights on how I could approach this, that would be helpful.

I will try to add a code example shortly with some of my failed efforts.

Comment: A possibility: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13857407/9297144

Comment: I think so, yes

Comment: other libraries do the same thing.  Check out: http://mathjs.org/examples/browser/plot.html.html

Comment: D3 is the wrong tool for this task. Have a look at my answer here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/133781/143592

Comment: Distance between points will vary based on the curve's derivative, there will be an error margin. If you zoom, re-sample and re-draw for that interval. It's not a big deal and it's not that bad.

Comment: Clearly D3 is not the best library for this task, but this is a much much smaller task in a larger project where D3 is appropriate. So I'm doing it in D3

Answer (score 2):

Yes thats quite possible. You can even use just the SVG DOM api and some helper functions but I made a fiddle with D3. I used most stuff minimally, 2 lines for coordinates and the function itself:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/emwhw8fz/3/

```
//generate points y = ax^2+bx+c
function createPoints(a,b,c,rangeX,step){
    return Array.apply(null,Array((rangeX[1]-rangeX[0])/step|0 + 1))
    .map(function(d,i){
            var x = rangeX[0]+i*step;
            return [x,a * x * x + b * x + c];
    })
}
//points
var points = createPoints(-0.1,0,80,[-30,30],0.5);
//create svg and path
var svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg").attr("viewBox","0 0 200 200");
//coordinates
svg.selectAll(".coordinates").data(d3.range(2))
.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("class","coordinates")
.attr("stroke","black")
.attr("d",function(d,i){
    return i
  ? "M0,100h200"
  : "M100,0v200"
});
//path
svg
.append("g")
.attr("transform","translate(100,100) scale(1,-1)")
.append("path")
.attr("stroke-width","2")
.attr("stroke","black")
.attr("fill","transparent")
.transition()
.delay(250)
.duration(1500)
.call(animate);
//animate
function animate(selection){
    this
  .attrTween("d",function(){
    return function(t){
     return "M"+points.slice(0,Math.max(1,t*points.length|0)).join("L");
    }
  }).each("end",function(){
    d3.select(this)
        .transition()
            .delay(250)
            .duration(1500)
            .call(animate);
  })
}
```